# Index value won't change

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to implement a linear search function to search for a particular number in which the user "inputs" however, say for example the user wants to search for the number 3 in the given array. The function should return an index value of 2. But my code returns 6 no matter what input I enter. I suspect there is something wrong in my main function (maybe while I am using a for loop, the value of i gets fixed to 6?). Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


#define numberOfElements 6
#define NOT_FOUND -1

int linearSearch (int *myArray, int key, int i);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

   int i, key, myArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
   printf("Input: ");
   for (i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++){
      printf("%d ", myArray[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
   printf("Please enter a number you wish to search for: ");
   scanf("%d", &key);
   linearSearch (myArray, key, i);
   printf("The number %d is at index %d\n", key, i);

   return 0;
} 


int linearSearch (int *myArray, int key, int i) {

   for (i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++){
      printf("Checking index %d\n", i);
      if (myArray[i] == key){
         printf("%d\n", i);
         return i;
         break;
      }
      printf("It's certainly not here!\n");
   }

   return NOT_FOUND;
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `i` into `linearSearch`? You return `i` back to `main`, but don't save the value, and seem to expect `i` to have changed due to the call to `linearSearch`. It would be helpful to review the way parameters are passed and values are returned in C.

Answer (score 5):

You ignore the return value from the `linearSearch` function.  Hence you don't print the answer.

Note that you should not pass `i` into the function but instead declare it within the loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<... etc
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not capturing the returned value of `linearSearch`.

You are passing it the value of `i`, but not a reference to `i`. Therefore, it doesn't matter what value you assign to it, it will not be available in `linearSearch`'s calling context.

As a result, you are ignoring anything `linearSearch` does.

I'd suggest removing the third parameter from `linearSearch` and just capturing its return value in a new variable and printing that.

Make the `i` inside `linearSearch` a local variable instead of an input parameter.

```
int linearSearch (int *myArray, int key) {

   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++){
      printf("Checking index %d\n", i);
      if (myArray[i] == key){
         printf("%d\n", i);
         return i;
         break;
      }
      printf("It's certainly not here!\n");
   }

   return NOT_FOUND;
}

/* ... */

int index = linearSearch (myArray, key);
printf("The number %d is at index %d\n", key, index);
```

Comment: Probably want to check `if ( index != NOT_FOUND )` after calling `linearSearch()`...

Answer (score 0):

Make this changes to your code:

```
    int linearSearch (int *myArray, int key);

    i = linearSearch (myArray, key);

    int linearSearch (int *myArray, int key, int i) {
      int i;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of the following things.

1. There is no use of passing the parameter i in function **linearSearch**. As you are not using the value passed.
2. linearSearch function returns the value i.

   k= linearSearch (myArray, key);

then u can print the value like this.

```
 printf("The number %d is at index %d\n", key, k);
```

Answer (score 0):

After you first  do the `for` loop to list your input array, the `i` value is `6`.

Then you reuse the `i` as a parameter of `linearSearch`.

You should know that when you call `linearSearch` with parameter `i`, you just put the value of `i` to the stack, and in the dinner of the function, any change to `i` will not affect the value of outside `i`. So you always get a `6`.

To correct this, you can change function call from
`linearSearch (myArray, key, i);`
to
`i = linearSearch (myArray, key, i);`

Then `i` will be changed to the return value.

Answer (score -1):

```
//It can work well if you correct it like this.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define numberOfElements 6
#define NOT_FOUND -1

int linearSearch (int *myArray, int key, int& i); **//"int i" changed to "int& i"**

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

   int i, key, myArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
   printf("Input: ");
   for (i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++){
      printf("%d ", myArray[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
   printf("Please enter a number you wish to search for: ");
   scanf("%d", &key);
   linearSearch (myArray, key, i);
   if(i != numberOfElements)
   printf("The number %d is at index %d\n", key, i);

   return 0;
}


int linearSearch (int *myArray, int key, int& i) { //**"int i" changed to "int& i"**

   for (i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++){
      printf("Checking index %d\n", i);
      if (myArray[i] == key){
         printf("%d\n", i);
         //return i; **//delete this statement**
         break;
      }
      printf("It's certainly not here!\n");
   }

   return NOT_FOUND;
}
```

Comment: This isn't C++, we don't have references. Your code will also return `NOT_FOUND` when it is found.